# How to make padding full width without any white space on both side of the screen?

Tags: html, css, padding

I see that most of the websites share a common thing which is the colour bar that extend to full screen across the screen. So I just supposed that this could be padding and if I making this padding width 100% it would make the width be REALLY full on both side. But unfortunately it appears that there is still a small white space on both side of the screen. Or this kind of colour bar is not supposed to be padding in the first place?

By the way, I'm really new to html and css so my code can be a bit messy and difficult to read.

These are pictures of my codes and the white space and you can see that there are slight space at both side of the screen.

[image]

Credit: Teamtreehouse

For example this site has the green bar across full screen without space on both side.

[image]

Comment: It will help you a lot to learn how to use the browser's [developer tools](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/) and read about css specificity.

Answer (score 2):

Set this

```
body {margin:0;padding:0}
```

because the body element has its default css rules

```
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px; /* and this might be the cause of your problem */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all browsers add some css themselves which varies from vendor to vendor.

Hence, you need to reset all browser css.
But to help you here's [normalize.css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/normalize)

just include this as your first css and it will automatically reset all custom-browser designing.